# Using Tweepy & TextBlob To Export Analysis To CSV In A Loop

Tags: python, tweepy, sentiment-analysis, textblob

I have coded an application that performs sentiment analysis on a topic and exports the tweets to a CSV file but it only exports a few tweets using Tweepy and TextBlob. I want to insert it into a while loop so it continues to run and add to the CSV file until I stop the program. Any help would be appreciated. Or any different way of doing it.

```
import tweepy
import csv
from urlextract import URLExtract
from textblob import TextBlob

consumer_key = 'KEY'
consumer_secret = 'KEY'
access_token = 'KEY'
access_token_secret = 'KEY'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

public_tweets = api.search('Trump')

with open('twitter_sentiment_analysis.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8", newline='') as output:
    fileOut = csv.writer(output)
    data = [['Tweets', 'Polarity', 'Subjectivity', 'URL']]

    fileOut.writerows(data)

    for tweet in public_tweets:
        analysis = TextBlob(tweet.text)
        polarity = analysis.sentiment.polarity
        subjectivity = analysis.sentiment.subjectivity


        url = None

        words = tweet.text.split()

        link = URLExtract()

        urls = link.find_urls(tweet.text)

        for word in words:
            # print (word)
            if 'http' in word:
                url = word

        fileOut.writerow([tweet.text, polarity, subjectivity, url])

        print(tweet.text)
        print('Polarity: ', polarity)
        print('Subjectivity:', subjectivity)
```

Comment: can you explain what the code you have here does and why it does not work?

Comment: Basically, the code does sentiment analysis on a predetermined twitter topic. This example is trump tweets. It then prints the analysis for about 5 tweets in the console and to a csv file but I want to analyze and print consistently in a loop.